# SELECT query is only SELECTING/CHECKING the first row, how do I SELECT/CHECK all

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, database

I have this simple query:

```
$q5 = "select listingid FROM userlisting WHERE userid = '$_SESSION[UserID]'";
$r5 = mysql_query($q5) or die(mysql_error());
$a5 = mysql_fetch_array($r5);
```

The userlisting table is a many to many relationship. It is used as a lookup table. Each userid can be associated with multiple listingids and vice versa.

Also in my file (a html template file) I have this code

```
if(!empty($_SESSION[UserID]) and $a5['listingid'] == $_GET['id']) :
```

So I am wanting to check if the listingid column in userlisting table = the id of the page (well, it is a property website and it is the id of the property). As each user can be associated with many listingids I need to be able to check multiple rows. But for some reason it only checks the very first row.

In the userlisting table there is the following test entries:
userid | listingid
1        1
1        2

So one user associated to two listingids. However, it is acting like this userid is only associated with listingid 1, the very first row.

Comment: Be careful about the concatenation of strings in your SQL query. If a user ID can contain an apostrophe or a backslash, without escaping or parameterisation it may break the query or allow the injection of unauthorised SQL.

Comment: If that's all your code you're only fetching the first row of any result set. Note also the `mysql_*()` has been deprecated and __will be removed__ in the next release of PHP. Don't use it for new code. Use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

You are only grabbing the first entry.

```
$a5 = mysql_fetch_array($r5);
```

This does not fetch the whole query result, but only the first row. If there is none, it will return `false`.

You have to create a loop to get more results.

Comment: I'd add, for the OP, that [the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) makes it quite clear what this function does. Always check the manual `:-)`.